# Split Pane divider change listener javafx

Tags: javafx, splitpane

I have two split panes which both have a vertical split . I`m trying to add a listener between the two divider so that when i move one split pane the other will move .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically:

```
SplitPane sp1 = ... ;
SplitPane sp2 = ... ;

// populate split panes...

// now bind divider positions:  
sp1.getDividers().get(0).positionProperty().bindBidirectional(
        sp2.getDividers().get(0).positionProperty());
```